# Android Studio - Documentation Popup Not Showing When Hover

Tags: android, android-studio

[Editor -> General -> Code Completion Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Qwl.png)

I've just updated Android Studio to the Hedgehog version. However, when I hover over a variable or code, the documentation popup doesn't appear. I've already adjusted the settings as shown in the image.

Is there any solution for this issue?